# Online Portuguese dictionary with IPA transcriptions

Tags: pronúncia, recursos-online, recursos

Are there any free, online Portuguese dictionaries (more complete than wikcionário) which provide IPA transcriptions?

Comment: On SO, requests for off-site resources get closed; and I guess the same holds on much of the SE network. Are you just testing out whether folks here agree that they're a bad fit? http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/324

Comment: @Filmsy You could try this one here; it belongs to Porto Editora, a very important publisher in Portugal: [http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/)

Comment: @Frank What a shame. :/ I'd like to answer this question even though the answer might be ephemeral. But I think a comment will suffice in this case! :)

Comment: @Frank: Then again on Travel.SE we welcome good resource questions and every site gets to make a lot of its own decisions. Keep in mind that SO is also seen as unwelcoming by many, so no need to copy all of its aspects.

Comment: Some sites also handle resource requests on their meta page.

Comment: Many SE sites allow such requests, many don't. I really don't think there's enough of a pattern to say there is a pattern at all.

Comment: I vote to leave open, but link-only answers should be discouraged. The answers have to try to explain what are the benefits, the cons, a short description, etc of the link provided.

Comment: I don't want to dissuade folks from posting answers just because this might be off-topic. @Flimzy I wasn't asking about a pattern so much as your opinion, since you've written about it before (in the link above) and have been active on a ton of SE sites, including as a (pro-tem) mod. But anyway, I'm fine with our deferring deciding the issue on this site until there are more examples to consider. Heck, maybe this will be the first and last resource request anyone tries to make.

Comment: @Frank I've reopened this question for now because we have not yet had the necessary community discussion about whether this sort of request is on-topic here, or on our meta, or nowhere at all. It it turns out it should be on our meta instead, we can always migrate it.

Comment: @Frank There are other examples: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade ; this seems like a necessary discussion to be had in meta. (I added a comment about this **[on our pt.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24028936#24028936)**.)

Comment: http://www.co.it.pt/~labfala/g2p/

Comment: Wiktionary actually has fairly good transcription in its entries

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for the phonetic transcriptions look no further:

http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=fonetica&act=list&region=lbx

If you are on linux, you could also use espeak to generate a transcription (not exactly IPA, but useful):

[image: espeak phonetic transcription]

And as @Flimzy pointed out, espeak does generate IPA with the `--ipa` option. Even though it is far from precise, it is still useful if your goal is improving your pronunciation.

<sub>Note: 
Please be more specific with your question. For example, explain why you need a phonetic dictionary that is online (and, probably, accessible through a browser), explain why the resources you have found do not suit your needs. Being more specific will help other people trying to help you, avoid trial-and-error answers (like this one) and simply make the board better.</sub>

Comment: espeak does output IPA with the `--ipa` option, but it (like the rest of its transcriptions) aren't very accurate.

Comment: [It says here that portal is still under test](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=fonetica), and  it certainly gives some controversial pronunciations for Lisbon. It renders ***Pateta*** as /p**ɐ**ˈtɛtɐ/. I've always heard /p**a**ˈtɛtɐ/], ***Ovelha*** is /u.vˈɐ.ʎɐ/. This one varies, but [infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ovelha) at least gives two: /ɔˈvɐ(j)ʎɐ, uˈveʎɐ/, and I like them better.

Comment: http://portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/ is very helpful.  It allows the user to specify a region, so I was able to find the IPA notation for some Portuguese words as spoken in São Paulo and Rio de Janeiro.  (I'd like to find a free, online speech synthesizer that can speak IPA, so I can double check the IPA sounds the way I expect.)

Answer (score 3):

I also found this research project where they created a pronunciation dictionary for Brazilian Portuguese (São Paulo City dialect). You can download the result as an Excel sheet. However, I can't judge its accuracy.

[Aeiouadô: a pronunciation dictionary for Brazilian Portuguese](http://www.nilc.icmc.usp.br/aeiouado/)

Answer (score 1):

Some further resources, including references given in comments:

- [Dicionário Fonético (ILTEC)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=fonetica) – phonetic dictionary with 70k+ entries
- [Grapheme to Phoneme Converter (g2p - pt-PT)](https://lsi.co.it.pt/g2p/index_en.html) – computer-assisted converter
- [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/) – established reference in pt-PT
- [TheFreeDictionary.com (PT)](https://pt.thefreedictionary.com/) – not as complete
- [v"ErbuS](https://lsi.co.it.pt//verbos/index_en.html) - Conjugation and pronunciation of verbs in pt-PT
- [Wikcionário](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcion%C3%A1rio:P%C3%A1gina_principal) – 270k+ entries, freely editable