# How's "m" in "bem" and similar words actually pronounced -- as [m] or more like [ng]?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, pronúncia

For instance, "bem", "sabem". On one hand, since these are "m", I'd pronounce them as [bem] and [sabem].

On the other hand, I've read an article of someone who's a poliglot and he says regarding switching from Spanish to Portuguese:

> Nasalising every n/m you see at the end of syllables (not between
>   vowels). The easiest way to get used to this at first is to imagine it
>   was written as “ng” in English. So “bem” (well) would be pronounced as
>   [beng] and “parabéns” (congratulations, and commonly “happy birthday”)
>   as [pa-ra-beng-s].

From movies and audios it's not clear whether similar words are pronounced with [m] or [ng].

What's the correct way?

Comment: Oh, Roman the Fabulist, I've heard about you!

Answer (score 5):

*[This answer needs to be refined to include the items raised by Jacinto in comments.]*

## Regarding *bem*

From the two options you present, the [ng] one is the closest one.

But although it's a good and helpful approximation, it's not quite correct.

### Listen directly to natives speaking it

You can listen to a few very good and distinct samples of diction in forvo:

https://forvo.com/word/bem/

NB: the one from "Bem1" is a Brazilian accent and not a Portuguese accent.

### IPA notation

The most correct IPA notation for *bem* is probably /ˈbɐ̃j̃/.

I can't figure out how /'bẽ/ or /'bɘ̃/ are invalid; those were my initial guesses.
I was also inclined to add a [velar nasal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_nasal) /ŋ/ at the end, but all online resources I found indicate that the nasalization with the /~/ is enough.

These are the different sources I found¹ for *bem*:

- /ˈbɐ̃j̃/ in [Instituto Camões](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/cpp/acessibilidade/capitulo2_1.html);
- /ˈbɐ̃j̃/ in [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/bem);
- /bˈɐ̃j/ in [Portal da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=fonetica&region=lbx&act=list&letter=b&start=940)

Unfortunately the online tool [phoneme-synthesis](https://itinerarium.github.io/phoneme-synthesis/) only supports English, and isn't capable of processing /~/ (for /ɘ̃/ etc.), /ɘ/, or e; otherwise we could refine this.

## Regarding -m endings

There are two groups of sounds for words ending in -m:

- -am;
- -em -im -om -um.

### -am (/ɐ̃w/)

These are past-tense forms, for the 3rd person plural of the Perfect Past and the Pluperfect:

- Falaram;
- Riram;
- Comeram.

It has the same sound as *-ão*: /ɐ̃w/.

### -em -im -om -um

These have a common ending to them, a nasalisation of the vowel.
This is represented with a [nasalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasalization), which in IPA is done using a tilde on top of the previous vowel:

- Bem: /bẽ/;
- Sim: /sĩ/;
- Com: /cõ/;
- Pum: /pũ/.

---

¹ Found in [Online Portuguese dictionary with IPA transcriptions](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/483/online-portuguese-dictionary-with-ipa-transcriptions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I've always felt that IPA is very complex and difficult - of course, how else could it be used for so many different languages and sound classes?!? So, I have a lot of doubts about this answer. I feel that the `bˈɐ̃j` and `ˈbɐ̃j̃` are missing the -m termination.

Comment: [there** are** two different sounds, and Portuguese]. Right, there is no nasal sound in English like the ão.

Comment: @ANeves, maybe it will help adding that in Portugal's standard accent *bem, sem, cem*, etc. ryme with *mãe* (but i Brazilian and southern Portuguses accents it sounds more like /bẽ/.

Comment: And *regam, pregam*, ryme with *orégão*, *pensam* rymes with *benção*. So there is no consonant sound at the end of the word (as you said of the *g*); the end *-m* just make the previous vowel nasal.

Comment: I'm trying my bestest of bests to be lazy, why must you torture me so? :(

Comment: I haven't yet incorporated @Jacinto's spot-on comments; I'll need to go at this again tomorrow.  Oof...

Comment: `The most correct IPA notation for bem is probably /ˈbɐ̃j̃/.` --> how do you pronounce `/ˈbɐ̃j̃/` ?

Comment: @roman, can you pronounce *mãe*? /ˈbɐ̃j̃/ rhymes with *mãe* (ˈmɐ̃j̃/ in IPA). You can listen to several people pronouncing [*bem* here](https://forvo.com/word/bem/#pt). The first two pronounce /ˈbɐ̃j̃/; that's the common pronunciation in Portugal. In Brazil it's more like /bẽj̃/, like Erikasb a bit further down on the same page, or simply /bẽ/, like Toinhoalam, the next one. It's hard to explain. For  /bẽ/ start with *bê* (intermediate between English ***be**d* and ***bi**d*, and arch up your tongue so that the back of it will get close to your palate. This will force air through your nose >>

Comment: >> and produce the nasal sound  /ẽ/. It's the same /ẽ/ as in *t**em**po* or *v**en**to* by the way. For /ˈbɐ̃j̃/ start with English *bay* and do the same thing with your tongue.

Comment: @ANeves, torture you so? It's for your own good. One day you'll understand.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be fooled by the letters *m* or *n*. There is no consonant at all at end of the word *bem*, or for that matter, in any words ending in *m* (more generally, whenever an *m* is followed a *b* or *p* or is in final position or when an *n* is followed by the other consonants). What the *m* indicates is that the previous vowel should be nasalized.

In the Lisbon dialect, *bem* is pronounced the same way as *mãe*, that is, with the diphthong /ɐ̃j̃/, but in other regions this merger didn't happen and it is pronounced /ẽj̃/. This is distinct from the monophthong /ẽ/ in *tempo*. /ẽj̃/ does not exist at all in Lisbon.

There are [reports of the nasal stop /ŋ/ being used in some dialects](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/os-sons-nasais-entre-palavras-no-norte-de-portugal/34236) and in Brazil, but this is not part of standard European Portuguese.

Comment: This is what I expected. Great answer! <3