# An online european portuguese dictionary with IPA

Tags: português-europeu

Does someone know of an online Portuguese dictionary with IPA which is complete?

I already know two but none of them give pronunciations for the verb conjugations like sou, somos etc only for ser and same for other verbs.

Is there any complete Portuguese IPA dictionary? I am only looking for European Portuguese.

[Online Portuguese dictionary with IPA transcriptions](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/483/online-portuguese-dictionary-with-ipa-transcriptions)
is a similar question but it does not answer my question completely as I am looking for a dictionary which conjugates verbs and provides its pronunciation as well in IPA.
The two dictionaries mentioned in this, Infopédia and Portal de Lingua Portuguesa, do not give any info on verb conjugations.

Comment: Welcome to Portuguese SE! This question (or a very similar one) has already been asked, so this post will be closed. Please consult the answers to its duplicate, but you may want to check this resources: https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcion%C3%A1rio:P%C3%A1gina_principal and https://lsi.co.it.pt//g2p/ .

Comment: Also this one, for verbs: https://lsi.co.it.pt//verbos/index_en.html

Comment: Raghav, one of the answers to the duplicate question, as well as the link in the comment above provide pronunciation keys for conjugated verbs, e.g.: eu sou | ˈeu sˈo ,  nós somos | nˈɔʃ sˈomuʃ , etc. Is not that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for I did not notice those links in that question before thank you so much stafusa

Comment: Alright, glad to help. Remember to upvote posts (questions and answers) you find are positive contributions.